# Convert String to Nokogiri node

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Is it possible to convert a string looking like this : `"<count>2</count>"` in Nokogiri node `<count>2</count>` ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and it's quite straightforward, just do

```
Nokogiri::XML("<count>2</count>")
```

For instance:

```
pry(main)> Nokogiri::XML("<count>2</count>").children.first.to_s                                              
=> "<count>2</count>"
```